# Spring integration | Service Activator - Error Channel , Exception handling

Tags: exception, spring-integration

I have a problem in catching the exceptions in my spring integration application.

Flow of operations in my application.

1. Http:inbound gateway which receives the request (error-channel defined to my custom error channel)
2. Service Activator for basic validations (Exceptions which are thrown from here are handled by error-channel defined on the GW)
3. splitter
4. Aggregator

Exceptions on my splitter or Aggregator are not handled by my error channel. why?

Steps taken:

I added a chain and included a header enricher and specified an error channel just before the splitter.

After this, any exception on my splitter is handled by my error channel mentioned in the header enricher.

```
<chain input-channel="invitations">
        <header-enricher>
            <error-channel ref="failed-invitations" />
        </header-enricher>
        <int:splitter ref="payloadSplitter" />
    </chain>
```

1. But the same doesnt work when do the same on my Aggregator. why?
2. Whenever there is an exception in my code, it retries and gets executed more than one time. why?
3. I have a "errorChannel" defined which logs the exceptions. it doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, not enough info. Whould be great if you'd share entire config to have a chance to reproduce it.

Comment: @Artem Bilan Added the config xml

Comment: You generally should not be messing with the headers that way; simply add an `error-channel` to the inbound gateway. We need to see much more of your configuration - for example, you don't have an `output-channel` on that chain.

Comment: @Gary Russell I was not able to post the complete xml here, due to size restriction. Please suggest a way to send you the complete xml

Comment: You can share it as public https://gist.github.com/. And leave comments on the lines, please.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have posted code here,  https://gist.github.com/siva6prakash/2d60cbde1212cd5ba090

Comment: @ArtemBilan Ive posted the code.

Comment: You're still messing with the header (`<int:error-channel ref="exceptionHandlingChannel" />`) - this is unnecessary when you have an error-channel on the gateway. What do you mean by "errors on the splitter or aggregator" ? Have you turned on DEBUG logging and followed the message flows?

Comment: @GaryRussell Initially I didnt have <int:error-channel ref="exceptionHandlingChannel" /> but any exception on the service activator in the "decisionChannel" chain was not handled by my error-channel on the gateway. After reading http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/72082-error-channel-service-activator I added header enricher and specified the error channel. now any exception on decisionChannel it gets directed to exceptionHandlingChannel. But any exception on my "getMessageChannel" is not getting handled.

Comment: That makes no sense to me; it's all running on the same thread. I see you have two components upstream of the aggregator but I don't see anything sending to `messageExistChannel`. You can't send mixed (foreign) data to the aggregator in this context without extra work. Like I said, turn on DEBUG logging and all will be clear. If you still can't figure it out, add your log to the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is too old, but I was also facing a similar issue and found I declared error-channel in header-enricher but not provide 'overwrite="true"' as a parameter. And after providing 'overwrite="true"'it is working as needed.  I am surprised why spring integration does not provide an overwrite=true by default.

Let us know this is what solution you did in your old code? So everyone can find out the solution for such a scenario.

Comment: It's a comment to the question. If you are not sure with your answer, you can post in a comment after gaining minimum required reputation.

Comment: I am sure this is the solution and as this is old post I request to see my answer and update all. So community can find an solution. Also if you are looking for similar issue please apply my solution and update all.