# Error is not propagated to my error handler while we are using dispatcher task-executor in Channel

Tags: spring-integration

Below is code snippets, where I am trying to handle an error.

```
<int:channel id="errorGateWayChannel"></int:channel>
<int:service-activator ref="errorHandler"
        input-channel="errorGateWayChannel" />
...
<int:service-activator.. />
<int-http:outbound-gateway ..>
<int:channel id="routerInputChannel">
<int:dispatcher task-executor="sharedPool"/></int:channel>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="routerInputChannel" output-channel="routerInputChannel1">
        <int:error-channel ref="errorGateWayChannel"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="routerInputChannel1" 
    default-output-channel="nullChannel">

<int:recipient channel="datasetInputChannel"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>
<int:service-activator id="datasetInputChannelSA" input-channel="datasetInputChannel"/> <!-- now this service activator giving me error -->
```

Now if "datasetInputChannelSA" service activator throw any exception I am getting WARN and that not propagate to error channel.

> WARN  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel - Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException:

I can see similar threads where they are getting WARN but not found how to handle it.

**Update:**
After providing overwrite="true" in "int:error-channel" it is working and sovle my issue.

```
<int:error-channel ref="errorGateWayChannel"/>
to
<int:error-channel ref="errorGateWayChannel" overwrite="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is not full enough to play with on our side, so, would be great to have some small project from you somewhere on GitHub to let us to reproduce an issue if that.

However, if you would like to handle errors from the `datasetInputChannelSA` and don't have any other problems, you need to consider to use a `<request-handler-advice-chain>` for that `<service-activator>` and include an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `trapException` as `true`. There you can configure a `failureChannel` to catch service exceptions and handle them in the consumer of that channel: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#expression-advice

It's already late to set a `error-channel` header in an `Executor` context: the failed message is not going to consult downstream headers. So, your error is propagated to the `TemporaryReplyChannel` header populated by the upstream gateway call (not shown in your code snippet though...).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to create git repository for the same in tomorrow my morning. Btw can you please explain bit more last paragraph that you have explained. I am new in SI so might not get what you are trying to say. Note: flow is working fine and it is going to error channel but after task executor channel it is not going for error channel. Not even OOB error channel. Can you please explain more how to handle error in task executor channel.

Comment: You can consider to use a `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` wrapper with a `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` and its `setDefaultErrorChannel()`. The problem with the `error-channel` header that there is no proper point of control. And it might not be propagated properly. Or like in your case: you are missing the fact that there is already a `errorChannel` header populated by the `@Gateway` and you don't override it. Although you even shouldn't. You may consider to configure an `errorChannel` on the `@MessagingGateway`. But that's already a speculation from your error: you just don't show that at all..

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for your reply, I have again go throw code and found that I need to provide overwrite="true" in header enricher in error-channel element.
Now, the question is why spring integration is not providing by default overwrite="true"? I can see others also facing similar issue i.e: below a post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387988/spring-integration-service-activator-error-channel-exception-handling/55155390#55155390

Also like to understand how error handling is done for http:inbound-getaway and why the temporary channel is created for that.